# Why does this not work?(school project btw)

Tags: input

```
import sys,time,random

typing_speed = 80 #wpm
def slow_type(t):
    for l in t:
        sys.stdout.write(l)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(random.random()*10.0/typing_speed)

slow_type("Hello which person do you want info for ")
inputs = input(
    "Type 1 For Malcom X, type 2 for Kareem Abdul-Jabbar             ")
if inputs == ('1'):
    inputs = input(
        "what info do you want.        1. overall life             2. accomplishments and obstacles.      3. His legacy   "
    )
    if inputs == ('1'):
        slow_type(
            "born in may 19 1925 in Omaha Nebraska his parents both died when he was a young child and there wasn't anyone who really could take care of him so he spent much of his time bouncing around different foater homes, in 1952 he joined the nation of islam and became a preacher,  he left the NOI to make a new group because he embraced a different type of Islam, sunni islam,    he died in febuary 21 on 1965 by assasins who were part of the NOI."
        )
    elif inputs == ('2'):
        slow_type(
            "Some of his major accomplishments include preaching islam and the message that the oppressed ahould fight back.   "
        )
if inputs == ('2'):
    inputs = input(
        "what info do you want. 1. Birth and age       2. Early Life.    3. Nba life      4. Later Life      5. Accomplishments and Accolades"
    )
    if inputs == ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'):
        if inputs == ('1'):
            slow_type(
              "Kareem was born in New York during 1947 on the day of April 16th  with the birth name of Lew Alcindor Jr. the son of Fernando Lewis Alcindor., New York policeman and Cora Alcindor. Later in his life Lew Alcindor changed his name to Kareem Abdul-Jabbar, meaning noble servant of the powerful One. Kareem is still alive today and is 74 years of age"
            )
        if inputs == ('2'):
            slow_type(
                "Kareem/ Lew Alcindor was always the tallest person in his class. When Kareem turned 9 he was already 5’8”. When he hit eighth grade he was 6’8”. Lew was playing basketball since he was young. At power memorial academy, Lew had a high-school career that nobody could match. Lew brought his team to 71 straight wins and 3 straight city titles."
            )
        if inputs == ('3'):
            slow_type(
                "In 1969 the Milwaukee Bucks selected Lew Alcindor with the first overall pick in the NBA draft. Lew quickly became a star being second in the league in scoring and third in rebounding, Lew was named the NBA Rookie of The Year. In the following season Lew became better and better and the bucks added future Oscar Robertson to the roster, making the Bucks the best team in the league with a 66-16 record. The bucks won the ring that year and Lew won MVP. Later that Summer Lew converted to Islam and Changed his name to Kareem Abdul-jabbar. Kareem and the bucks got to the NBA finals that year but lost to the Celtics. Even with al the success with the bucks Kareem struggled to be happy. Later that off season demanded a trade to either The Lakers or the Nicks. The bucks complied and traded Kareem to the Los Angelos Lakers where he was paired with Magic Johnson, making the lakers by far the best team in the league. During the rest of Kareems career he dominated the NBA winning 5 more titles and wining 5 more MVPs."
            )
        if inputs == ('4'):
            slow_type("o")
```

To be specific the info doesn’t print for some reason pls help owo uwu I’m a furry cat girl

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because your logic.

`if inputs == ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'):` will always return `False` as your `inputs` variable will never be that tuple. You are also overwriting the `inputs` variable and I would consider renaming those distinct.

I made a few changes in there. Take a look and compare it to your code. This code is working just fine (relative to what you provided).

```
import sys,time,random

typing_speed = 80 #wpm
def slow_type(t):
    print('\n')
    for l in t:
        sys.stdout.write(l)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(random.random()*10.0/typing_speed)

slow_type("Hello which person do you want info for?")
inputs_alpha = input(
    "Type 1 For Malcom X, type 2 for Kareem Abdul-Jabbar\n--> ")
if inputs_alpha == '1':
    inputs = input(
        "what info do you want?\n1. overall life\n2. accomplishments and obstacles.\n3. His legacy\n--> "
    )
    if inputs == '1':
        slow_type(
            "born in may 19 1925 in Omaha Nebraska his parents both died when he was a young child and there wasn't anyone who really could take care of him so he spent much of his time bouncing around different foater homes, in 1952 he joined the nation of islam and became a preacher,  he left the NOI to make a new group because he embraced a different type of Islam, sunni islam,    he died in febuary 21 on 1965 by assasins who were part of the NOI."
        )
    elif inputs == '2':
        slow_type(
            "Some of his major accomplishments include preaching islam and the message that the oppressed ahould fight back.   "
        )
if inputs_alpha == '2':
    inputs = input(
        "what info do you want?\n1. Birth and age\n2. Early Life.\n3. Nba life\n4. Later Life\n5. Accomplishments and Accolades\n--> "
    )
    if inputs in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']:
        if inputs == '1':
            slow_type(
              "Kareem was born in New York during 1947 on the day of April 16th  with the birth name of Lew Alcindor Jr. the son of Fernando Lewis Alcindor., New York policeman and Cora Alcindor. Later in his life Lew Alcindor changed his name to Kareem Abdul-Jabbar, meaning noble servant of the powerful One. Kareem is still alive today and is 74 years of age"
            )
        if inputs == '2':
            slow_type(
                "Kareem/ Lew Alcindor was always the tallest person in his class. When Kareem turned 9 he was already 5’8”. When he hit eighth grade he was 6’8”. Lew was playing basketball since he was young. At power memorial academy, Lew had a high-school career that nobody could match. Lew brought his team to 71 straight wins and 3 straight city titles."
            )
        if inputs == '3':
            slow_type(
                "In 1969 the Milwaukee Bucks selected Lew Alcindor with the first overall pick in the NBA draft. Lew quickly became a star being second in the league in scoring and third in rebounding, Lew was named the NBA Rookie of The Year. In the following season Lew became better and better and the bucks added future Oscar Robertson to the roster, making the Bucks the best team in the league with a 66-16 record. The bucks won the ring that year and Lew won MVP. Later that Summer Lew converted to Islam and Changed his name to Kareem Abdul-jabbar. Kareem and the bucks got to the NBA finals that year but lost to the Celtics. Even with al the success with the bucks Kareem struggled to be happy. Later that off season demanded a trade to either The Lakers or the Nicks. The bucks complied and traded Kareem to the Los Angelos Lakers where he was paired with Magic Johnson, making the lakers by far the best team in the league. During the rest of Kareems career he dominated the NBA winning 5 more titles and wining 5 more MVPs."
            )
        if inputs == '4':
            slow_type("o")
```